# scrapy how to get project name from inside a scrapy project

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

for some import issue, i would like to know if there is any variable i can call from inside a scrapy project to get the project name, because i keep doing imports like

```
projectname.something..
```

and these imports are dynamically and during the run time i choose which module i want to import so if there is a way to get the project name, that would make everything easier

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still not sure why do you need it, but the [`settings.BOT_NAME`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html#bot-name) would contain your project name:

> The name of the bot implemented by this Scrapy project (also known as
>   the project name). This will be used to construct the User-Agent by
>   default, and also for logging.
>
> It’s automatically populated with your project name when you create
>   your project with the startproject command.

```
from scrapy.conf import settings

print(settings.BOT_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

Scrapy provides a convenient way to access attributes specified in the projects setting's file.

> If you are inside a Scrapy project there are some additional helpers you can use to import those components within the project. You can automatically import your spiders passing their name to CrawlerProcess, and use get_project_settings to get a Settings instance with your project settings.

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()

BOT_NAME = settings.get('BOT_NAME')
```

Remember to use **.get()** method as the attributes are not directly accessible.

For complete details refer to [this link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html).

Do comment for any doubt. Tested with Scrapy 1.5.1 .